# Install npm module in a known directory

Tags: node.js, shell, npm

`npm install hello-world` creates a `node_modules` directory inside of my current directory.

How can I download and install `hello-world` in a known directory?

---

For example, how can I download and install the npm module in `dir2` directory?

```
.
|- dir1
|- dir2
|- dir3
+- dir4
```

Comment: Just navigate to that folder and run npm from there

Comment: @adeneo No, it will just create a `node_modules` directory in that directory.

Comment: Then just move the contents out of that folder

Comment: @adeneo Yeps. But I guess there should be an argument that passed will install the npm package directly inside of my path.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/faq.html#node_modules-is-the-name-of-my-deity-s-arch-rival-and-a-Forbidden-Word-in-my-religion-Can-I-configure-npm-to-use-a-different-folder

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are confusing npm packages that can be used globally (usually as some type of command line interface), and modules that are reusable libraries loaded by your custom node app.

The `node_modules` folder created by `npm install` is for the latter case - reusable library modules.  You can certainly move the `./node_modules/hello-world` folder to `./dir2`; however, this goes against the grain of node, and will make it very, very hard to ship your app using `npm publish`.

If `hello-world` is a really cool cli utility, just use `[sudo] npm install -g hello-world`.  This should then enable you to run the `hello-world` command in your shell.

Comment: No, I don't confuse them. I just want to download any npm package in a  known directory (instead of `node_modules/package-name`).

Comment: Ok.  You are fighting the "node" way of doing things. You are going to have to do something like `npm install hello-world && mv -f node_modules/hello-world ./dir2`.  I imagine a shell function/alias would make this easier. You are going to confuse anyone else that works on your system by doing this.